# The named parameter elevation is not defined,

Tags: flutter, dart, cardview

i'm newbie in flutter and i'm getting this error, The named parameter 'elevation' is not defined
please anyone who can help please

```
body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
        height: 220,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5.0,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with the code block from the question.

If you did something with your code base, e.g. change the folder etc. Try to reload vs code, maybe something is wrong with the vs code analyzer plugin. If not, the problem is in another part of the code.